# Is it possible to combine the Euler-Lagrange equations with the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

In particular, say we seek a sufficiently smooth function $ u : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ such that the solution $x$ to the differential equation with given initial conditions

$$ G(x, x', \dots, x^{(n)} ; u, u', \dots, u^{(m)}) = 0, \quad x^{(k)}(0) = \alpha_k, k=0,\dots n $$

extremizes (or at least is a critical point of) the functional

$$ \int_a^b F(x, x', \dots, x^{(n)} ; u, u', \dots, u^{(m)}) dt $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. I think the particular theory you are looking for is discussed in the section "holonomic and non-holonomic constraints" of the following book :

[The Calculus of Variations](http://books.google.ca/books?id=McBCbLDjXk0C&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=calculus%20of%20variations%20holonomic%20constraints&source=bl&ots=wFeF_nN2vn&sig=HVWXKmPBOD-Kztemt2EAH58bof4&hl=en&ei=nvvuTd3nH4fx0gHPmej3DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

This method can be used, for example, in order to compute the geodesics on a surface such as the sphere. The condition would simply be $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$ and the functional optimize would be arc length.